# Couldn't find Photo with id=16

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Not sure why this isn't working but I've been mis-guided I think....I'd rather not re-route but simply have the photo uploaded in the current landing_welcome page.. not be transfered to an update template.

error:

```
Couldn't find Photo with id=16 [WHERE "photos"."attachable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."attachable_type" = $2]

def update
@user = current_user.photos.find(params[:id])
@user.update_attributes!(person_params)
redirect_to @user
end
```

Users_controller.rb
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

```
  def update
    @user = current_user.photos.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes!
    redirect_to @user
  end

  def show

  end
end
```

**landing_welcome.html.erb**

```
 <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">                                                                                                            
                  <%= nested_form_for current_user, :html=>{:multipart => true } do |f| %>                                                                    
                    <%= f.fields_for :photos do |p|  %>                                                                                                       
                    <p>                                                                                                                                       
                    <%= image_tag(p.object.file.url) if p.object.file? %>                                                                                     
                    <%= p.label :file %><br />                                                                                                                
                    <%= p.file_field :file %>                                                                                                                 
                    </p>                                                                                                                                      
                    <%= p.link_to_remove "Remove this attachment" %>                                                                                          
                    <% end %>                                                                                                                                 
                    <%= f.link_to_add "Add photos to your profile", :photos %>                                                                                
                    <br /><br />                                                                                                                              
                    <p><%= f.submit %></p>                                                                                                                    
                    <% end %>                                                                                                                                 
                  </div>
```

routes.rb

```
root to: "home#landing"

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "users/registrations",
    :sessions => "users/sessions",
    :passwords => "users/passwords"}

   get "welcome", to: "home#landing_welcome"

  devise_scope :user do
  #  get "edit/edit_account", :to => "devise/registrations#edit_account", :as => "account_registration"                                                       
    get 'edit/edit_account' => 'users/registrations#account_registration', as: :edit_account
  end

  patch '/users/:id', to: 'users#update', as: 'user'
```

photo.rb

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :file

  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true

  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email,
                  :password,
                  :password_confirmation,
                  :zip,
                  :gender,
                  :remember_me,
                  :first_name,
                  :last_name,
                  :birthday,
                  :current_password,
                  :occupation,
                  :address,
                  :interests,
                  :aboutme,
                  :profile_image,
                  :photos_attributes

  has_many :photos, as: :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
  mount_uploader :profile_image, ProfileImageUploader

  validates :gender, :presence => true

  def number_of_users
    User.all.count
  end

end
```

Comment: id's aren't supposed to start with numbers.

Comment: @GaryHayes, don't you mean id's aren't supposed to start with `$`?

Answer (score 1):

For lack of a better answer, I think your woes lie in the query generated by your app:

```
Couldn't find Photo with id=16 [WHERE "photos"."attachable_id" = $1 AND "photos"."attachable_type" = $2]
```

Two factors are present here:

1. Why is your `attachable_id` being called as `$1`?
2. Why is your `attachable_type` a number, not a string?

---

**Polymorphic Association**

Your query is trying to load a `Photo` with `ID=16`, however, your query is also trying to validate the model, to satisfy the polymorphic association. This is where the error is coming from

As you've not stated which route / page this error is showing, I can only speculate as to the cause of the problem:

```
@user = current_user.photos.find(params[:id])
```

This query is really bad for a number of reasons:

1. You're using the `current_user` object directly. I might be wrong here, but this is used by Devise / Warden to store relative information about the logged-in user, and is not a real ActiveRecord object (with relational data etc)
2. You're trying to `.find` on top of a relation (`current_user.photos`)

Although this might be incorrect, I would look at doing this for that query:

```
@photo = User.joins(:photos).find(current_user.id).where("photos.id = ?", params[:id])
```

Then you can perform the updates you require